# DateTime.Now returning different times on local and azure app service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, datetime, azure-web-app-service

I am from west India. `DateTime.Now` returning current time when debugging from Visual Studio. But when I hosted it on an Azure App Service, it is returning 6 hours earlier time. The App Service is hosted in West India. I added App Setting for the App Service `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` to `Indian Standard Time` and restarted the App Service but still the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Indian Standard Time` is not supported as App Service's timezone name, check  supported time zone names [here](http://jackstromberg.com/2017/01/list-of-time-zones-consumed-by-azure/) (Check exact spelling of the tz name in left-side column).

Best practise is to use UTC time in server context and convert it to local time in UI.

Comment: Ok but the list in the link contains `India Standard Time`.

Comment: Check exact spelling in `Name of Time Zone` left-side column.

Answer (score 1):

Azure server times runs on UTC by default. This way you could calculate the difference from the user time. There is also the option to use `DateTime.UtcNow()`